# scipy error, but no exception raised

Tags: python, exception, scipy, interpolation

i've encountered a usual scipy.interpolate error :

```
>>> sx = interpolate.UnivariateSpline(T,X)
  File "...scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py", line 143, in __init__
    xb=bbox[0],xe=bbox[1],s=s)
dfitpack.error: (m>k) failed for hidden m: fpcurf0:m=3
```

Is there some Python Exception attached to this error ? (i just want to intercept the exception and ignore it)

If not, how can I do to continue running my program ?
Thanks

### I'm back a few hours later, to give a solution :

this piece of code, to catch exception and raise my own exception.:

```
try : 
   sx = interpolate.UnivariateSpline(X,Y)
except : 
   raise PyGlideSplineError("%s : impossible de calculer la spline"%whoami())
```

It works !!!

Thank you

Comment: Pierre: not that I directly know of, but any chance you can make a self-contained program that reproduces this? (That is, add values for `T` and `X` so other people can try this as well.)

Answer (score 5):

`scipy.interpolate.dfitpack` is an extension that does not seem to expose the exception type directly to Python. However, you can cause a deliberate error to scare the exception from its hiding place, catch it, and store its type in a variable:

```
from scipy.interpolate import dfitpack

try:
    dfitpack.sproot(-1, -1, -1)
except Exception, e:
    dfitpack_error = type(e)

try:
    dfitpack.sproot(-1, -1, -1)
except dfitpack_error:
    print "Got it!"
```